# How can I create a weighted pyramid chart (looks like a pie chart)?

Tags: d3.js, charts, highcharts

I haven't been able to find any examples of pyramid charts resembling the one below. I only have this drawn image as an example, but most of the similar implementations I've found are just for pyramids or regular, circled pie charts.

[image: Pyramid]

Comment: I'm not aware of any examples of this in D3.

Comment: How about using a radar chart as a starting point? Like: http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/6506614 or similar. You can then easily re-weight etc.

Comment: How does the value of each category ("Cost"..) affect the look of the chart?

Comment: @Ondkloss it works similar to a radar chart (as suggested above this comment), where the a particular section (eg, "Cost") would take a bigger portion of the triangle, with relation to the other's values (like a pie chart).

Comment: @PinguinDirk the "radar chart" indeed looks closer to what I am looking for, although since it visually looks more complex than a "simple" triangle, how would I draw or shape the radar chart to resemble a triangle (or any specific shape, I guess)?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I added an answer, I hope this is what you were looking for! (there are other `svg` elements you might want to use (like `svg:polygon, but in your case, I think a simple `path` should do - and is much more versatile :))

Comment: The bigger question is why would you want to? This is taking a pie chart, which is already a poor way to display data, and making it even more difficult to determine the relative values of each section...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment. I looked into it, it seems to me that you can quite easily get something like that using a path generator.

Find my implementation here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/chroth/5nx9Lpke/1/

What did I do?

(1) create some simple path generator (closed path)

```
function pathGen(d) {
    return ('M 0 0 ' +
    'L ' + rad * Math.sin(2 * pi * d[0]) + ' ' + rad * Math.cos(2 * pi * d[0]) +
    'L ' + rad * Math.sin(2 * pi * d[1]) + ' ' + rad * Math.cos(2 * pi * d[1]) +
    'Z');
}
```

This essentially takes a data point of the form `[x,y]` and draws the segment.

(2) Next, we add a function that converts weights to data points:

```
function dataGen(arr) {
    var total = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b
    });
    var runner = 0;
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result.push([runner, runner + arr[i] / total]);
        runner += arr[i] / total;
    }
    return result;

}
```

(3) using these components, we can then just push in weights and get the corresponding graphs, like so:

```
var data = dataGen([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]);
```

(4) Apply some formatting, cross fingers, run it:
[image]

Or using other weights like `[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2]`:
[image]

**NOTE**
Personally, I am no big fan of radar charts and similar, as it depends a lot on the order of the weights. You can modify my path generator easily to a fully functional radar chart by parametrizing the `rad` parameter.
Also, in this implementation, you will notice that weights that vary a lot look weird.
Still, I hope this will get you started with your chart idea!

Good luck.